# What is lost if we completely exclude free variables from ZFC?

Tags: logic, set-theory

Just as an example, in some places the Axiom Schema of Comprehension is formulated with a free variable for example Kunen:

Axiom 3. Comprehension Scheme. For each formula, φ, without y free,
$\exists y \forall x (x \in y \longleftrightarrow x \in z \land \phi(x))$

In other places such as Wikipedia and Hrbacek, Jech formulates it without free variables:

The Axiom Schema of Comprehension: Let P(x) be a property of x. For
any set A, there is a set B such that x ∈ B if and only if x ∈ A and P(x).

There is a difference in what can be deduced inside ZFC (I mean without using model theory or semantic resources) between

$\exists y \forall x (x \in y \longleftrightarrow x \in z \land \phi(x))$

and

$\forall z \exists y \forall x (x \in y \longleftrightarrow x \in z \land \phi(x))$ ?

In general, What is lost if we completely exclude free variables from ZFC?

I know that "There is nothing specific in  regarding free variables" but we can build a ZFC theory where all formulas are closed. What limitation may have that theory?

Comment: No difference; in mathematics, when we asserts a formula, like e.g $x+y=y+x$, we assume that the free vars are implicitly **universally** quantified. Thus, [Axiom of Separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Statement) $∃y∀x(x∈y ⟷ (x∈z \land \varphi))$ must be read as $∀z∃y∀x(x∈y⟷(x∈z \land \varphi))$.

Comment: @bof It is not an axiom it is an axiom scheme. That is an axiom for each possible formula φ.

Comment: @bof Right. I will edit it.

Comment: I hope you do appreciate that you need to use formulas with free variables to carry out proofs in the standard presentations of first-order logic. However the inputs (axioms) and outputs (theorems) of proofs can always have their free variables quantified without making any significant difference.

Comment: @RobArthan No, I don't. Can you explain it? Can you give an example?

Comment: Look at the proof rules for your favourite presentation of first-order logic. You will find they make essential use of formulas with free variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact Kunen's book has all the axioms as closed formulas: in both Axiom 3 (Comprehension) and Axiom 6 (Replacement) it says "the universal closure of the following is an axiom"; the other axioms are all single closed formulas.

Comment: So there is not any formal lost getting rid free variable from ZFC, it is just a matter of presentation. Right?

Comment: Indeed, in Mendelson's Introduction to Mathematical Logic both forms would be formally deducible from each other.